# javascript array in array to postgres parenthesis

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql

I have an array of array of values that I make using `.map()`:

```
let my data = [ [ "ted", 20 ], [ "jon", 30 ], [ "bob", 25 ] ]
```

And I am creating a `sql` statement in `postgres` which needs to end up with:

```
values (("ted", 20),("jon", 30),("bob", 25))
```

Is there an easy way to put this into `postgres`.  I can change it to just text in the `.map()` method, but I would like to keep it as an usable array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to generate the desired string. This won't change the original `data`.

```js
function toValuesStr(data)
{
    let values = data.map(([k,v]) => `("${k}", ${v})`).join(",");
    return `values (${values})`;
}

let data = [[ "ted", 20 ], [ "jon", 30 ], [ "bob", 25 ]];
console.log("String:", toValuesStr(data));
console.log("Data:", data);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```